# At what time of the day does the S3 objects get transitioned to S3-IA or Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have Object A uploaded to my S3 bucket on 2nd August 2018 at 9:00:00 AM.

Let's say i have put Lifecycle rule for the transition to Standard-IA **One** day after object's creation date.

Will the object A gets transitioned to Standard-IA at 3rd August 2018 at 9:00:01 AM? or it will get transitioned to Standard-IA at 3rd August 2018 00:00:01 AM?

Comment: I've heard that it takes place overnight, but the pricing benefit kicks-in immediately. However, I do not have a reference for that.

Comment: Thank you for the response.:) I am really hoping to find some AWS docs about that.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you are right I tryto explain this in answer and provided the link to aws blog post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per AWS Documentation and [Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/) and chat I once had with AWS Support team:

> **Expiration** – Specifies an expiration period for the objects that are
>   subject to the rule, as a number of days from the object’s creation
>   date.
>
> **We calculate the expiration date for an object by adding that object’s
>   creation time to the expiration period and rounding off the resulting
>   time to midnight of that day**.

**AWS Calculates everything with UTC**.

Let me try to explain with example :

I put an object at **Aug 2,2018 9:00 AM IST** that would be **UTC 3:30** with **one day deletion** or transition criteria, So Amazon will **check On Aug 3 UTC 00:00** if the criteria is met but as you can see one day is not done thus it will **take no action**.

Now on A**ug 4 UTC 00:00** it will again check if and this time the criteria will be met and thus the object **will now be deleted**.

Hope this clarify!

Comment: Thank you for providing details. This means My object created at 9:00 AM IST gets transitioned to Standard - IA after 44.5 Hrs 

(2nd August 03:30 AM UTC to 4th August 00:00 UTC = 
20.5 Hrs + 24Hrs = 44.5 Hrs )

after object creation even though the transition rule is 1 day. So basically everything is calculated wrt UTC.

Comment: yes exactly , if the answer helped you kindly mark it as solution i.e resolved.